# Help a newbie (rkhunter warnings)

Tags: malware, rkhunter

Recently, I got very suspicious that somebody has ratted my system. I feel the tabs will sometimes change. For example I do something on chrome and suddenly it shows opera screen (even though they're both running, I never clicked the opera screen) and stuff like that.

So I downloaded rkhunter, did a test by running `sudo rkhunter -c --enable all --disable none` My output is below.
Are all of those fake warnings or is there actually something I should be worried about?

```
Warning: The command '/usr/bin/lwp-request' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/lwp-request: a /usr/bin/perl -w script, ASCII text executable
Warning: The following processes are using deleted files:
         Process: /sbin/upstart    PID: 1394    File: /home/qwerty/.cache/upstart/window-stack-bridge.log.1
         Process: /usr/bin/nautilus    PID: 1806    File: /home/qwerty/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 2001    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.bsY3ZP
         Process: /bin/cat    PID: 2007    File: /dev/pts/7
         Process: /bin/cat    PID: 2008    File: /dev/pts/7
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 2147    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 2220    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 2222    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 2682    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 2992    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 3491    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
         Process: /usr/lib/firefox/firefox    PID: 3626    File: /dev/pts/7
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 3760    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
         Process: /usr/lib/firefox/firefox    PID: 3824    File: /dev/pts/7
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 4057    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
         Process: /usr/bin/unity-scope-loader    PID: 4331    File: /tmp/tmpfHAIWlu
         Process: /usr/share/discord/Discord    PID: 5634    File: /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.k92K46
         Process: /usr/share/discord/Discord    PID: 5687    File: /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.k92K46
         Process: /usr/share/discord/Discord    PID: 5712    File: /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.5ZDa2W
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 6182    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 7917    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 24709    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
         Process: /opt/google/chrome/chrome    PID: 28812    File: /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.rKGMNn
Warning: File '/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.mEHtjR' (score: 274) contains some suspicious content and should be checked.
Warning: Checking for files with suspicious contents [ Warning ]
Warning: Process '/sbin/dhclient' (PID 1036) is listening on the network.
Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-1350328584: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-731875246: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-2797972517: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-2509473639: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-477054089: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-934396546: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-2102280203: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-3302084726: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-528687106: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-3145487857: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-1815311782: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-2150163244: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-3711979297: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-194223215: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-2010166027: data
```

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what you mean by "did a test"?

Comment: sudo rkhunter -c --enable all --disable none

Comment: Did you update the properties database before you ran your check?

Comment: Yes, i did sudo rkhunter --update

Comment: and sudo rkhunter --propupd

Answer (score 0):

After a quick review of your output as well as the [rkhunter howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RKhunter) the only thing that would give me any concern in your output is "File '/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.mEHtjR' (score: 274) contains some suspicious content and should be checked." As this is in your /tmp folder it's likely it would be gone after a reboot but it wouldn't hurt to check again. It's my understanding that you should do a `sudo rkhunter --propupd` first to update the database of file properties (this has to be done every time new software is installed) See the [howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RKhunter) for details.

`sudo rkhunter --versioncheck` will tell you if there's a newer version available than the one you are using.

The suspicious file types in /dev/shm appear to be normal pulseaudio files but appearances can be deceiving so I make no guarantees.

You might wish to subscribe to [Rootkit Hunters mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rkhunter/lists/rkhunter-users) which is a good source of info on false positives.

Sources:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RKhunter

`man rkhunter`